# Nikon D800 Wireless i-TTL range

Tags: nikon, flash, wireless-flash

I have been experimenting with my new Nikon SB-910 speedlight using the Wireless i-TTL Advanced Wireless Lighting System that nikon has kindly built into the D800, which i believe to be radio based (as opposed to IR/flash trigger)

However I am struggling with range - I only seem to be able to get upto about 4 meters from the camera before the speedlight refuses to fire.

I am unable to find any data regarding the range I should expect to be able to get out of the system, or much real data at all TBH.

I am fully aware that there are long range remote trigger kits available, but want to see what the nikon system limits are first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nikon's wireless system is not radio based; it is flash-triggered. That's really the only downfall to the system, but it's a big one. Flashes basically need to have line-of-sight to each other. Bright conditions (such as outside) can be difficult, particularly when the sun is shining directly into the IR sensor on the flash. That said, under the right conditions and being sure to aim the IR sensor at the firing flash, I've triggered it at about 150 feet (about 50 meters?) away.